# method not recognized in rspec integration testing despite module included in spec_helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting an error that my method is not defined. The error is "undefined local variable or method 'mock_auth_hash', despite including the module which defined mock_auth_hash in the spec_helper.

I'm trying to do some rspec integration testing with omniauth and I'm following this link https://gist.github.com/kinopyo/1338738

Please help me figure out what's wrong because I've spent way too many hours trying to figure this one out...maybe I need a fresh pair of eyes on it...

Here are my files

spec->support->omniauth_macros.rb

```
module OmniauthMacros
    def mock_auth_hash
        OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = {'provider' =>"facebook",
                                        'uid' =>"12345",
                                        'info'=>{'name'=>"John Doe"},
                                        'credentials'=>{'token'=>"AAABBBCCC"}}
    end
end
```

spec->spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
.
.
.
config.include OmniauthMacros #I've also tried putting config.include(OmniauthMacros)
.
.
end

OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
```

spec->requests->game_pages_spec.rb

```
describe "signing in" do
        before {visit root_url}
        mock_auth_hash
        before {click_button "Login with Facebook"}
        it {should have_selector('h1',text: 'Welcome')}
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `mock_auth_hash` has to go within a `before` or `it`.

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe it was that simple.